# How to create matrix for heatmap by group in R?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, heatmap

I have a example data as follows, I want to create a heatmap where the average sleep duration hour (SLP) is shown according to 3 recruiting site(site) and 5 recruiting year(year).

```
SLP site year sex
8.6  1   2008  1
7.2  1   2005  2
6.4  2   2006  2
9.5  3   2007  2
6.1  2   2009  2
5.1  3   2008  1
2.1  2   2006  2
3.6  1   2001  1
8.6  1   2008  1
7.2  1   2005  2
6.4  2   2006  2
9.5  3   2007  2
6.1  2   2009  2
5.1  3   2008  1
2.1  2   2006  2
3.6  1   2001  1
```

In the heatmap I want to make, x axis and y axis are year and site, respectivly, and each cell include mean duration of sleep duration.

I don't know how to make the matrix from data frame for making heatmap.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, and it also depends on how you want to create the heatmap. If you want to use `ggplot2` then you do not need to modify the `data.frame`. For example, this should work:

```
txt <- "SLP site year sex
8.6  1   2008  1
7.2  1   2005  2
6.4  2   2006  2
9.5  3   2007  2
6.1  2   2009  2
5.1  3   2008  1
2.1  2   2006  2
3.6  1   2001  1
8.6  1   2008  1
7.2  1   2005  2
6.4  2   2006  2
9.5  3   2007  2
6.1  2   2009  2
5.1  3   2008  1
2.1  2   2006  2
3.6  1   2001  1"

d <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
d$year <- factor(d$year) # make year a factor.

ggplot(d, aes(x = site, y = year, fill = SLP)) + geom_tile()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact, I want to heatmap with complexheatmap package which requires to make matrix from data frame set. if possible, please answer the my new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266610/how-to-create-the-matrix-from-data-frame).