# How to create the matrix from data frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

i have a data frame as follows, I want to create a matrix, where the average sleep duration hour (SLP) is shown according to 3 recruiting site(site) and 5 recruiting year(year).

```
SLP site year 
8.6  1   2008  
7.2  1   2005  
6.4  2   2006  
9.5  3   2007  
6.1  2   2009  
3.6  1   2005 
8.6  1   2008  
7.2  1   2005  
6.4  2   2006  
9.5  3   2007  
6.1  2   2009  
5.1  3   2008 
2.1  2   2006
```

My desired output is:

```
       1      2      3 
2005  6.00    -      -
2006   -     4.97    -
2007   -      -     9.5
2008  8.60    -     5.1
2009   -     6.10    -
```

Column name is variable of site, row name is variable of year and values in each cell is average of SLP. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `acast`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, year~site, value.var="SLP", mean)
```

---

Or using `tapply` from `base R`

```
with(df1, tapply(SLP, list(year, site), FUN = mean))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few different solutions which use no packages:

**1) tapply** This uses no packages. It produces a `"matrix"` output with NA values for the empty cells:

```
tapply(DF$SLP, DF[c("year", "site")], mean)
```

giving:

```
      site
year     1        2   3
  2005 6.0       NA  NA
  2006  NA 4.966667  NA
  2007  NA       NA 9.5
  2008 8.6       NA 5.1
  2009  NA 6.100000  NA
```

**2) aggregate/xtabs** This uses `aggregate` + `xtabs`.   This creates an object of class `c("xtabs", "table")` with zero values for empty cells:

```
fo <- SLP ~ year + site
xtabs(fo, aggregate(fo, DF, mean))
```

giving;

```
      site
year          1        2        3
  2005 6.000000 0.000000 0.000000
  2006 0.000000 4.966667 0.000000
  2007 0.000000 0.000000 9.500000
  2008 8.600000 0.000000 5.100000
  2009 0.000000 6.100000 0.000000
```

**3) aggregate/reshape**  This also uses `aggregate` but uses `reshape` rather than `xtabs`.   It gives a data frame `r` with NA's for empty cells.  The last line makes the column names consistent with the prior solutions and could be omitted if this were not important.

```
 ag <- aggregate(SLP ~ site + year, DF, mean)
 r <- reshape(ag, dir = "wide", idvar = "year", timevar = "site")
 names(r) <- sub(".*[.]", "", names(r))
```

giving:

```
> r
  year   1        2   3
1 2005 6.0       NA  NA
3 2006  NA 4.966667  NA
5 2007  NA       NA 9.5
2 2008 8.6       NA 5.1
4 2009  NA 6.100000  NA
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form used is:

```
DF <- structure(list(SLP = c(8.6, 7.2, 6.4, 9.5, 6.1, 3.6, 8.6, 7.2, 
6.4, 9.5, 6.1, 5.1, 2.1), site = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), year = c(2008L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2009L, 2005L, 2008L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2009L, 2008L, 2006L
)), .Names = c("SLP", "site", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 2):

another solution

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df%>% 
  group_by(year, site) %>%
    summarise(m=mean(SLP)) %>%
  spread(site, m )%>%
as.matrix()
```

Comment: You don't need any of the "." included as the first argument in your commands (e.g. `df %>% group_by(year, site)` will work just as well as the first two lines you have). Tidyverse verbs automatically expect a dataframe as the first argument and will use whatever is piped to them unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @g-grothendieck's use of xtabs, we can combine this with `table` and `ifelse` to return the same result.

```
# get a count of the number of observations per matrix cell (filling 0s with 1)
tempTab <- ifelse(with(df, table(year, + site)) == 0, 1, with(df, table(year, + site)))

tempTab

year   1 2 3
  2005 3 1 1
  2006 1 3 1
  2007 1 1 2
  2008 2 1 1
  2009 1 2 1
```

Now use `xtabs`, which returns a sum of the values when multiple observations are in a cell and divide by tempTab to get the mean.

```
xtabs(SLP ~ year + site, df) / tempTab
      site
year          1        2        3
  2005 6.000000 0.000000 0.000000
  2006 0.000000 4.966667 0.000000
  2007 0.000000 0.000000 9.500000
  2008 8.600000 0.000000 5.100000
  2009 0.000000 6.100000 0.000000
```